# Passing large number of parameters to a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, parameters

I have a requirement wherein I have to save a large number of parameters from UI to database (Oracle 11g).  There's also some business logic involved, so I have decided to use a Stored Procedure.  But passing around 100 parameters to stored procedure seems ugly and performance intensive.

There's an option of using Object Types, but that's Oracle specific.  Is there a generic solution to tackle this problem?

Even a non stored procedure approach is welcome.

Comment: Try using temp tables. the application can populate a temp table which you can later manipulate using a stored procedure.

Comment: What language is your UI written in? I would suggest using an ORM (e.g. Hibernate in Java, or NHibernate or Entity Framework in .NET) to avoid using Stored Procedures at all.

Comment: @RB. My UI is written in Java/JSP.

Comment: if you cling to (plsql) stored procedures you may also opt for collection arguments to your stored procedure.